# XML Attribute Value Normalization

Tags: xml, parsing, whitespace

I'm reading the XML specification at W3C, and this part of the section on [attribute value normalization](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#AVNormalize) caught my attention:

> If the attribute type is not CDATA, then the XML processor MUST further process the normalized attribute value by discarding any leading and trailing space (#x20) characters, and by replacing sequences of space (#x20) characters by a single space (#x20) character.

Does this mean that

```
<tag attr=" a      b " />
```

is equivalent to

```
<tag attr="a b" />
```

Or am I misinterpreting what the specification says?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct, given that the 'attr' type is *not* CDATA, but most probably it is.

The annotated XML specification helped me a lot when scrutinizing the details:
http://www.xml.com/axml/testaxml.htm

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example to supplement the correct answer by @Per Norrman (+1) and the example you used in your question.

```
<!DOCTYPE tag [
<!ELEMENT tag EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST tag
          attr NMTOKENS #IMPLIED>
]>
<tag attr=" a      b "/>
```

is equivalent to

```
<!DOCTYPE tag [
<!ELEMENT tag EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST tag
          attr NMTOKENS #IMPLIED>
]>
<tag attr="a b"/>
```

because the attribute type of `attr` is `NMTOKENS` (plural).

However the following would not be equivalent to the `NMTOKEN` example because `attr` is literal text (CDATA = character data):

```
<!DOCTYPE tag [
<!ELEMENT tag EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST tag
          attr CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
<tag attr=" a      b "/>
```

This is because the attribute type of `attr` is CDATA.